# How to kill Interactive Report when it takes a long time?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an Interactive Report and sometimes it takes a long time.
I want to kill that when it takes more than 1-min.
How can I do this?

Comment: Press BACK on your browser?

Comment: @Littlefoot It not good because process in Database still working if press back.
It work on users systems and I want to stop it automatic

Comment: Besides killing the session for the particular process that you're running (which I can't particularly say is a good practice), what you can do is analyze the query you have in your report and to find the reason to why it is  running that slow. From my experience, the only time a report would get hung like this is if I had a humongous query that was either inneficient or badly written, such as a first draft.

Comment: @AWildmann That's right. I have to find it. Thanks